# Unable to locate element: //*[@id="US-6"] with xpath

Tags: python, windows, selenium, web

I am experiencing the following problem.

I'm trying to select the next size every time I find this:

```
| error, selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
locate element: // * [@ id = "US-6"] |
```

I would like to avoid the end of the script
and it try to click

```
// * [@ id = "US -7 "]
```

without interrupting the script.

I have no idea if it's possible. I really need help.

Comment: It's an exception, catch it with a try except and use the others xpath.

Comment: yuup it works perfectly many thank's :)

Comment: Feel free to validated my anwser by checking the check button under the up/down vote one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id = "US-6"]') 
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('// * [@ id = "US -7 "]')
```

Comment: hi Florian you can help me on this quesion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922181/python-auto-checkout-with-requests?noredirect=1#comment104105942_58922181

Comment: @ciaobuonasra I can't, I don't have the knowledge to help you with your question.