# Python auto checkout with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, checkout

I’m trying to buy a product on the website, with a requests python’s library.
For keep the cookies in the session i’m using requests.Session() and all the post requests are made with the most common headers.I’m using dev tools for reproduce the POST requests and converter it from curl to python with trillworks.com, but at the payment page i got: the cart content is changed (obv it pisn’t).
My questions are:
-It’s enough make a POST requests?(i’m doing in this way)
-i’m reproducing only xhr requests . I'm doing it wrong?
My code for keep the cookies and reproduced the common headers it the follow:
What should i do?
`session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {key:value, ...}`

Comment: if you are already logged in using session then you don't have to add anything to the headers instead check the post parameters maybe it's using a token or something that needs to be sent along with the purchase info

Comment: I send a token for adding the object at the cart but seems that there isn’t a token ti send at the payment. I noticed there are two get request of timestamp for the object reservation but when i try to replay it i got missing some data, but there are no POST before those two GET that send that data; furthermore, the data that is missing is required in the next phase (payment phase)